# MysQL Get Time via Query

Tags: php, mysql

The time in row 'Signup' is stored like this: "1427538785"
So I am not able to use this method: `WHERE DATE(Signup) = DATE(NOW())`

But need to get the query where time of signup is today..

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME() converts to a datetime

Answer (score 1):

You need `from_unixtime`

```
mysql> select from_unixtime('1427538785','%Y-%m-%d');
+----------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime('1427538785','%Y-%m-%d') |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2015-03-28                             |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the query will be

```
WHERE from_unixtime(Signup,'%Y-%m-%d') = curdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Signup)) = curdate()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It answers the question with the solution.

Comment: As a very high rep user please don't fill up the low quality review queue with a code dump only answer. We have enough of them from the newcomers. `This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.`